# Fastest strings binary file | grep

Tags: android, linux, shell, grep, sh

I use the following linux shell commands to count number of words in a big **binary file** which takes too much time (~10 secs);

```
strings /path/to/<binary_file> | grep -c -E "word1|word2|...|wordN"
```

How can I speed up the process?

I tried using only the `grep` command, but it cannot find some words, so I must use `strings`. I tried to add `wc` instead of `-c`, but that is slower.
BTW, I don't have parallel command in Android environment.

*Actually I still could not write the C equivalent of this combination, any help will be appreciated.*

Comment: Does it fail to find some words because you thought `-c` counted words instead of lines?

Comment: This combination can find all the words in binary correctly, I see it when I print the words using `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Forewords

First of all, your command has several flaws that will make it fail in certain situations:

- It won't work with words made of non-ASCII characters like accented letters since they are filtered by `strings`. You may not be looking for such words though.
- It will miss words with less than 4 characters if they are isolated. You should use `strings -n1` for a generic solution.
- It will miss words when multiple words belong to the same line of text because `grep -c` count lines, not words.

Issues with the Android's implentation of `grep` (as of Android 8.1):

- On Android, you must use `grep -E 'word1|word2|...|wordN'` instead of `grep -F -e word1 -e word2 .. -e wordN` which is equivalent but usually significantly faster. This is because there is a bug in Android 8 that makes the latter not count properly.
- On Android, I will not just use `grep -a` but `grep -za`. On Linux, GNU grep treats NUL (0) characters in a binary file as end of lines, and the `-z` option is not only useless but not desirable as the output lines would be also terminated with NUL instead of a newline. But the Android version is behaving differently: NUL characters need to be explicitly treated as newlines, otherwise what follows is ignored; by chance lines are still output with a traditional newline.

### Limiting the output of `strings`

You will probably get a slight speed gain by setting the `-n` option to `strings` to the size of the smallest word you are looking for. For example, if none of the words you are looking for is less than 7 characters long, use `strings -n7`. Thus, you will lower inter-process communication, and your `grep` won't bother searching lines that, obviously, won't fit the pattern.

### Getting rid of `strings`

`strings` is a bit expensive and might be of little benefit (it depends on the amount of binary characters that are filtered out - YMMV, see my comment in the next section), or even be detrimental (see my forewords). You may get rid of it with:

```
grep -F -a -o -e word1 -e word 2 ... -e wordN /path/to/binary_file \
| wc -l
```

Because of the aforementioned issues with Android's `grep`, here is the Android's version:

```
grep -z -a -o -E 'word1|word2|...|wordN' /path/to/binary_file \
| wc -l
```

Remember that using `grep | wc` is mandatory since `grep -c` does not count words but lines. That's why `grep -c` looks quicker to you, because once it has found a word, `grep` counts +1 and continues with the next input line, possibly missing other words on the current line.

### Parallelizing

Depending on your number of cores, you may also achieve a good speed-up by parallelizing your `grep`s:

```
( grep -F -a -o -e word1 -e word2 /path/to/binary_file &
  grep -F -a -o -e word3 -e word4 /path/to/binary_file
) | wc -l
```

Because of the aforementioned issues with Android's `grep`, here is the Android's version:

```
( grep -z -a -o -E 'word1|word2' /path/to/binary_file &
  grep -z -a -o -E 'word3|word4' /path/to/binary_file
) | wc -l
```

Here I'm assuming that the most intensive processing is done by `strings` and `grep` and, due to their filtering, that `wc`'s work is minor. It may not be the case depending on the search pattern. Similarly, if `strings` is doing a great job filtering out the binary file, it's probably preferable to keep it as the first instruction. YMMV.

### Using `tr` instead of `strings`

`strings` may filter out a good deal of unnecessary (non-ASCII) characters and this can truly help `grep` process less data. You can go even further by filtering out every character that does not belong to the words you are looking for. For example, if you look for "word1", "word2" and "word3", you can filter out all the characters that are not w, o, r, d, 1, 2, 3.

If you have access to the `tr` command line tool, you will get benefits using it instead of `strings`:

```
tr -c -s 'word123' '\n' < /path/to/binary_file \
| grep -F -o -e word1 -e word2 -e word3 \
| wc -l
```

Because of the aforementioned issues with Android's `grep`, here is the Android's version:

```
tr -c -s 'word123' '\n' < /path/to/binary_file \
| grep -E -o 'word1|word2|word3' \
| wc -l
```

(beware that `tr` does not work with non-ASCII multi-byte characters but since you are using `strings` in ASCII mode, you already don't care about this)

### Benchmarking

Here are some tests done on a 24 MB sound file; the platform being my Android 8.1 octacore mobile phone. Depending on your input file, the search strings and your number of cores, you'll obviously get other results, but that will give you an idea of the possible speed improvements.

```
# Your original command (fixed)
$ time strings -n1 test | grep -E 'A|B|C|D' -o | wc -l
403380
    0m18.93s real     0m10.05s user     0m13.77s system

# grep alone
$ time grep -z -a -E 'A|B|C|D' -o test | wc -l
403380
    0m07.03s real     0m05.26s user     0m00.04s system

# Parallelized grep (x2)
$ time ( grep -z -a -E 'A|B' -o test &
         grep -z -a -E 'C|D' -o test
       ) | wc -l
403380
    0m03.56s real     0m03.12s user     0m00.03s system

# Parallelized grep -F (x4 - one per string to search)
$ time ( grep -z -a -F A -o test &
         grep -z -a -F B -o test &  
         grep -z -a -F C -o test &
         grep -z -a -F D -o test
       ) | wc -l 
403380
    0m01.04s real     0m01.88s user     0m00.05s system

# tr instead of string
$ time tr -c -s 'ABCD' '\n' < test | grep -E 'A|B|C|D' -o | wc -l
403380
    0m01.60s real     0m01.27s user     0m01.41s system

# Parallelized tr + grep (x2)
$ time ( tr -c -s 'AB' '\n' < test | grep -E 'A|B' -o &
         tr -c -s 'CD' '\n' < test | grep -E 'C|D' -o
       ) | wc -l
403380
    0m00.95s real     0m01.23s user     0m02.20s system
```

As you can see, with these test conditions, there is a ~20x speed improvement between the version with `strings` and that last one (with `tr` and parallelized).

Comment: I gave it a try, your suggestion cannot find some words and as a performance it seems slower.
`time strings /system/bin/app_process | grep -c -E "Android|android"
41
    0m00.10s real     0m00.13s user     0m00.00s system
time grep -F -a -o -E "Android|android" /system/bin/app_process | wc -l
43
    0m00.11s real     0m00.16s user     0m00.02s system`

Comment: Answer updated. What I see from your test case is that your command miss some words, not mine. BTW, if you want to compare times, why not try on the actual binary file, 10 seconds is not that long and the results would be more relevant. Have you done a speed-test on the parallelized greps?

Comment: Hello, I have tried the parallelized greps are OK but grep itself missing some words. For example strings | grep finds 6440 words, but grep finds just 26. So if you have any suggestion about parallelized strings | grep option, I can try it. About the tr, unfortunately I could not get it running, it gives errors about usage of tr.

Comment: @Phillip Can you double-check that the commands you used are exactly the same as mine? I have tested all of them on a 100M file of pure random content and all gave me the same result (on Linux though, not on Android).

Comment: I'm working on Android 7.0 and `tr` command gives errors with those parameters, I think it is a limited command in Android. Anyway as I said, `grep` cannot find all the words alone, I must add `strings` for help. Maybe I can try something like this : `strings <file> | (grep word1 & grep word2 & ... & grep wordN) | wc -l` is this also parallelizing the search? If yes, if I can use `grep -c` 
 without `wc -l` somehow, it can be even faster. What do you think?

Comment: I have tried the following commands and results shows that fastest is `strings <file> | grep -c -E "word1|word2"` https://0bin.net/paste/dNlMQdqtNcp37J4s

Comment: I've just tried the toybox version of `tr` on Oreo with those parameters, and it works perfectly. Don't know for Nougat. You may want to try without the `-s` option, as it is just an optimization. I have also tested my commands and all run fine and yours, with `strings`, is by far the slowest. As for `grep -c`, I have explained in my answer why it is faster than piping to wc: because it misses words. What is the point of using a counting method that is inaccurate?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `<` part to the `tr` command. Now it worked and found more words than `strings | grep` combination, but execution time is 3 times longer.

Comment: @Phillip You were right in that there are some issues with Android's implementation of `grep`. I have amended my answer. I have also added some benchmarks that you may find useful.

Comment: I accept this answer in fact that I have learned a lot from you. You can add a parallelized `strings` variant also for comparison. I don't know why, but `tr` command works slower on my Android 7 phone. Actually I have more than 30 words and for the `tr` or `strings` limitation, I must make a dictionary before start searching. But indeed I believe that will help for performance. Thank you for your help. Your are the best!

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome. A parallelized `strings` is easily predictable: see how the parallelized versions of `grep` and `grep+tr` divide the total time by (approx.) 2. What matters is that you have enough free cores for twice the number of processes. If you have a quad-core and you are using your browser to watch videos, you will have to share your CPU cores for that processing and you won't halve the total time.